# Tomcat7 JDBC pools

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, amazon-web-services, tomcat7

I have the following in META-INF

```
<Context>
   <Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        name="jdbc/TestDB"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
        username="mysql_user"
        password="mypassword123"/>
</Context>
```

In my web.xml I have

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In my Java code I have

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource datasource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
con = datasource.getConnection();
```

When Tomcat is starting up I get the following error and I have mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar in my libs folder. Any idea why?

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
05-Jun-2012 23:16:29 org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:242)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:175)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:684)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:616)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:479)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:135)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:114)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:101)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:501)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:224)
at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1061)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:671)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:235)
... 29 more
```

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I am having the exact same problem :( Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Also having this issue... Its weird!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the JDBC drivers for MySQL.

Download them from MySQL's website: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Add the driver to your classpath, to your project, or to Tomcat's HOME\lib directory.

Comment: I have mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar in my apps lib directory. I know mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar gets picked up as I have other servlets which do not use JDBC pools and they work. Something todo with startup?

Comment: Yeah, probably some other configuration file is loading when you run the application. Try adding the MySQL driver to your CLASSPATH or to Tomcat's HOME\lib directory. If that works then you've narrowed it down to config.

Comment: How do I add mysql to the classpath? I am new to Tomcat / web apps. Also I am running this on Amazon BeanStalk so I don't have access to tomcat

Comment: In that case follow this guide to setup MySQL on BeanStalk: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.rds.html

Comment: So I added mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar to Tomcat's HOME\lib directory and it worked. So it seems during startup when reading the context.xml tomcat cannot read the web-inf/lib jars or do I need to reference the mysql jar in the context.xml?

Comment: I have used spring to manage the pool instead and all works fine

Comment: Thanks. I put mysql connector and tomcat-jdbc.jar in Tomcat lib

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue on Ubuntu with Tomcat7 installed by the apt-get mechanism. The problem was the dbcp used by Tomcat, more specifically commons-dbcp.jar instead of tomcat-dbcp.jar.

To resolve this, I took `catalina*.jar` and `tomcat-dbcp.jar` from a copy of Tomcat7 downloaded from the tomcat site and replaced the files in tomcat's lib folder. (`commons-dbcp.jar` replaced with `tomcat-dbcp.jar`).

See [this link](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/installation-upgrades/solved-get-java-error).